# Number of non-recursive combinations of variables

Tags: combinations

For mathematically minded people, this is probably an easy one. Unfortunately, I am not one of those, and therefore I am too dumb to even know how to do an effective google search or searching already asked questions here. So, I am sorry if this was answered already.

My problem is: I have three variables; A,B,C. I want to know how many combinations of these exist when order does not matter, and I ignore single variables. So in the case of A,B,C there are 4 combinations: A:B, A:C, B:C and A:B:C.

How can I generalize that to n variables? I am looking for a formula where I can input the number of variables and get the number of combinations.

Comment: Technically, if you're talking about "all" combinations, then you have 8 possibilities. i.e:
$\{\}, \{A\}, \{B\}, \{C\}, \{A,B\}, \{A,C\}, \{B,C\}, \{A,B,C\}$. In general, for n items, there are $2^n$ total combinations. If you don't want combinations containing $r$ items (like in your example you didn't include 0 items or 1 item) you can subtract those off like so:
$$2^n - \sum_{r}\binom{n}{r}$$
Note that $\binom{n}{r}$ is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: So in your example where u subtracted off combinations with 0 items and 1 item, you'd do $2^3 - \binom{3}{0} - \binom{3}{1} = 8 - 1 - 3 = 4$

Comment: So the formula you're looking for is $$2^n - n - 1$$

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much!